# Error while executing ionic 2 application

Tags: ionic2

For my sample ionic 2 application, I am getting below error when below command is executed from windows 10 command prompt.

```
ionic serve
```

[image]

Any idea what could be the reason for this error ?

Comment: Do you install npm with same user?

Comment: yes.. I do have

Comment: Run cmd as an administrator and see what appens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have uninstalled and installed cordova and ionic again . This has fixed the issue.